# ngClass not updating after condition is changed in a callback

Tags: angularjs, callback, ng-class

I am trying to add a 'loading' class to an element until an asynchronous call is finished. To do so, I am using a variable named  **loading** that I use like so:

```
<div class='ui segment' ng-class="{'loading': loading == true}">
```

To trigger the call, I am using another element with **ng-click** :

```
<i class='...' ng-click="action('deleteGlobal', false)"></i>
```

This will call the method **deleteGlobal** of the variable *project* in my controller's *$scope*, and provide a callback :

```
$scope.action = (action, redirect) => {
    delete $scope.error;
    $scope.loading = true;
    $timeout(() => {
        $scope.project[action]((err) => {
            $scope.loading = false;
            if (err)
                $scope.error = err;
            else if (redirect)
                $state.go('projects.all');
        });
    })
}
```

*project* is an instance of my custom class **ProjectManager**. This is its method **deleteGlobal** :

```
deleteGlobal (callback) {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
    }, 1000)
}
```

(Here, the setTimeout is only used to simulate a long operation since that is what I plan to replace this code with later on)

So with this code, I expect *$scope.loading* to become false once the callback is called. And with a couple of *console.log*s I saw that was indeed the case. However, the 'loading' class of my element is not removed accordingly.

I read about $scope.$apply() and tried to wrap my async call in it but it didn't work. In fact, it even triggered an error: '$apply already in progress'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only need `$scope.$apply` for code that executes outside of angular. Namely, the callback you pass to `window.setTimeout()` needs to be wrapped in `$scope.$appy`.

If you use angular's `$timeout` service instead, you won't have to call `$scope.$apply` because angular will do it for you.

Comment: How can I access $scope or $timeout outside of the controller ? The ProjectManager class is in a separate file

Comment: I would consider this very bad practice unless I had a really compelling case for doing it. That said, you might try something like creating a global reference to your $rootScope in a run block. Then call $apply on it from your external code. (Now I feel like I need a shower.)

Comment: Do you mean creating a class in a separate file is a very bad practice ? Why is that so ? Should I instead write every piece of code in my controller ? I'm not sure I understand :\

Comment: No I mean doing what I said above would be very bad practice. But it's one way to sort of brute-force integration with third-party non-angular code.

Perhaps I misunderstood you, though. If you're saying you wrote a custom class to be used in your AngularJS app, then just register its constructor as an Angular service, which will then have access to $timeout.

Comment: Thanks, I think this may be the solution to my problem. One more thing though: in my controller, I instantiate a ProjectManager object, but if I understood services correctly, that's not how it works. The problem is I need to pass an object as a constructor to ProjectManager, and then use it. So I'm kinda stuck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Integrating callback-based APIs with AngularJS

In general with AngularJS, third-party callback-based APIs are integrated with the framework by converting them to $q promises:

```
function apiPromise(callbackBasedApi) {
    var defer = $q.defer()
    callbackBasedApi( (value,err) => {
         ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶b̶a̶c̶k̶(̶)̶;̶  
         if (value) {
            defer.resolve(value);
         } else {
            defer.reject(err)
         }; 
    })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Then use the `.then` method of the returned promise:

```
$scope.action = (action, redirect) => {
    delete $scope.error;
    $scope.loading = true;
    var promise = apiPromise($scope.project[action])
      .then(function(value) {
        if (redirect)
           $state.go('projects.all');
        };
    })
      .catch(function(err) {
        $scope.error = err;
    })
      .finally(function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
}
```

Promises created with the [`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) are integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will automatically benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.